# C++: Is It Possible to End a Non-Void Function Without a Return?

Tags: c++, function, templates, break

This is a fairly general question, but long story short, I'm trying to figure out a way to break out of a function without using return. I've got a function built from a template, so my compiler doesn't like me using "return;" to terminate early as I've seen suggested before. Here is a condensed version of what I'm trying to do:

```
V & find (K key) {
    TreeNode<K,V> *traverseFind;
    //TreeNode<K,V> * treeNode = new TreeNode<K,V> (key,NULL);
    traverseFind = root;
    unsigned int compareTraverseToHeight = 0;
    //A bunch of stuff happens
    if(keyFinder == 0)  //this is what I have tried to do
        return;
    return traverseFind->value; //This is what I'm working with, the value can be NULL
}
```

Some background: this is a find function within a binary tree, which contains two parameters key and value. A key is searched for, and then its corresponding value is returned. As part of the project, I've been tasked with throwing an exception which is caught by a tester function if a key is entered which isn't in the tree. This works fine, however, the way the tester program is configured throws me right back into the function after being resolved, in which case I have traverseFind->value = NULL, which crashes my program when I try and return it. I have no control over the tester, so I'd like to break out of the find function before I have to return a value.

Most of this is background for the curious. My real question is: instead of the if(keyFinder ==0) function that I have tried to use (which doesn't compile), is there another option I can use to end the function early? A "break" statement for functions, so to speak?

MORE CODE:

```
#ifndef __CSC116__BST_H__
#define __CSC116__BST_H__

//
// An implementation of a binary search tree.
//
// This tree stores both keys and values associated with those keys.
//
// More information about binary search trees can be found here:
//
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
//
// Note: Wikipedia is using a different definition of 
//       depth and height than we are using.  Be sure
//       to read the comments in this file for the
//   height function.
//

#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned int heightCount = 0;
unsigned int sizeCount = 0;
int keyFinder = 0;



//
// Each node in the tree stores
// both a key and a value
//
template <class K, class V> class TreeNode
{
public:
    TreeNode(K k, V v): key(k), value(v), left(0), right(0) {}

    K       key;
    V       value;
    TreeNode<K,V>   *left;
    TreeNode<K,V>   *right;
    template <class X, class Y> friend std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream &s, const TreeNode<X,Y> &t);
};

// 
// TreeNodes can output themselves to streams
template <class K, class V> std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &s, const TreeNode<K,V> &n)
{
    s << "\"" << n.key << ":" << n.value << "\"";
    return s;
}

//
// This exception is thrown if you try to find 
// a key in the tree that isn't present.
//

class key_not_found_exception {

};



template <class K, class V> class BinarySearchTree {
public:
    //
    // Constructor
    //
    BinarySearchTree ()
    {
        sizeCount = 0;
        heightCount = 0;
        root = NULL;
    }


    ~BinarySearchTree()
    {
    }


void insert (K k, V v) {
  TreeNode<K,V> * treeNode = new TreeNode<K,V> (k,v);
  TreeNode<K,V> *temp=NULL;
  TreeNode<K,V> *prev=NULL;
  temp = root;

  while(temp) { 
    prev = temp;
    if (temp->key < treeNode->key)
      temp = temp->right;
    else
      temp = temp->left;
  }

  if (prev==NULL)
    {root = treeNode;heightCount++;}
  else {
    if (prev->key<treeNode->key)
      {
        prev->right = treeNode;  
        if(prev->left ==NULL){heightCount++;}
      }
    else
      {
        prev->left = treeNode;
        if(prev->right ==NULL){heightCount++;}
      }
  } 

  sizeCount++;
  cout << "Height of Tree is:"<<"_" <<heightCount<<endl;
}






    V & find (K key)                     
    {

    TreeNode<K,V> *traverseFind;
    //TreeNode<K,V> * treeNode = new TreeNode<K,V> (key,NULL);

    traverseFind = root; 
    unsigned int compareTraverseToHeight = 0;

    while (compareTraverseToHeight < heightCount) 
    {
        if (traverseFind == NULL)  // We've fallen off the tree without finding item.
        {
            keyFinder = 0;
            cout<<"code1"<<endl;
            cout<<"keyFinder = 0"<<endl;
            break;

        }

        else if ( key == traverseFind->key )// We've found the item. 
        {
            keyFinder = 1;   

            cout<<"code2"<<endl;
            cout<<"keyFinder = 1"<<endl;
            break;
        }       

        else if ( key < traverseFind->key )                   // If the item occurs, it must be in the left subtree,
        {                                                 // So, advance the runner down one level to the left.
            traverseFind = traverseFind->left;

            cout<<"code3";
        }   


        else  // If the item occurs, it must be in the right subtree. // So, advance the runner down one level to the right.
        {
            traverseFind = traverseFind->right;

            cout<<"code4";  
        }  


         compareTraverseToHeight++;      

    }  // end while

    cout<<"At end of loop, keyFinder ="<<keyFinder<<endl;

        try
        {
            if(keyFinder ==0)
            {
                cout<<"Try has found that keyFinder = 0"<<endl;
                throw key_not_found_exception();

            }
            else{cout<<"keyFinder = 1"<<endl;}
        }catch(...){}

        cout<<"RETURNED";
        cout<<traverseFind->value<<endl;

            if(keyFinder == 0)
            {

            }
            return traverseFind->value;



    }

private:

    unsigned int doHeight (TreeNode<K,V> *t)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    void        doDelete (TreeNode<K,V> * n )
    {
    }

    TreeNode<K,V>   *root;
    unsigned int    count;
    unsigned int    sizeCount;

#endif
```

TESTER FUNCTION

```
void test_insert_find()
{
    BinarySearchTree<string,string> t;

    t.insert("bob", "bobdata");
    t.insert("joe", "joedata");
    t.insert("jane", "janedata");

    try
    {
        cout<<"Looking for Bob"<<endl;
        string s = t.find("bob");
        if (s != "bobdata")
            throw bst_tester_exception(__func__,__LINE__);
    }
    catch (key_not_found_exception &e)
    {
            throw bst_tester_exception(__func__,__LINE__);
    }

    try
    {
        cout<<"Looking for Sarah"<<endl;
        string s = t.find("sarah");
        throw bst_tester_exception(__func__,__LINE__);

    }


    catch (key_not_found_exception &e)
    {

        cout<<"Successfully caught"<<endl;
        // this is expected.
    }
```

FULL OUTPUT OF TEST:

```
Looking for Bob
code2
keyFinder = 1
At end of loop, keyFinder = 1
keyFinder = 1
RETURNEDbobdata
Looking for Sarah
code4code4code1
keyFinder = 0
At end of loop, keyFinder = 0
Try has found that keyFinder = 0, throwing exception
RETURNED /*Program now crashes when it attempts to return NULL*/
```

Comment: What do you suppose the caller would do if you did have a way to return without a function result?

Comment: I would imagine the program would just continue to run?

Comment: Yes, you can end it with [`longjmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp), or by `throw`-ing an exception as well. Not what you are looking for? How about `exit(...)`, `abort()` and the like?

Comment: I'll look into longjmp, I wasn't familiar with it. Don't exit and abort terminate the whole program, though? That's not what I'm trying to do, I'd just like to skip past the return if I'm stuck with a NULL value and keep going. Either that or return a neutral value, but the fact that I'm using a template parameter seems to prevent that.

Comment: Reaching the end of a non-`void` function is Undefined Behavior, with one exception: `main` has an implicit `return 0;`.

Comment: *"This works fine, however, the way the tester program is configured throws me right back into the function after being resolved"* You throw an exception, which is caught, and the your function which has thrown the exception is continued? What is this? Windows Structured Exception Handling?

Comment: You can [`exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), [`abort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort), `throw` again, or default-construct (or set some sentinel state in) a `static` `V` object inside the function and return a reference to that....  Anyway, if you've got a completely stupid test system, why bother?

Comment: To take the thinking of @InternalServerError to the next step: how will the caller know that nothing has been returned?

Comment: dyp - to be honest, the way the tester function is configured is well beyond my knowledge level. I get an output when calling this function for bob (in tree) and sarah (not in tree) that resembles this, though:

Looking for Bob/
keyFinder = 1/
RETURNEDbobdata/
Looking for Sarah/
keyFinder = 0/
Try has found that keyFinder = 0, throwing exception/
RETURNED /*Program now crashes when it attempts to return NULL*/

I can post the whole code if wanted, but essentially, it indicates that the exception is successfully called, resolved, and then leaps back into the function.

Comment: Well I'd really like to see how that tester "leaps back into the function". One can answer your question without that knowledge, but the whole issue might be an xy-problem related to that tester.

Comment: Tony - because my grade isn't affected by how stupid the test system is :P

Michael-would it matter? Would the program not just leap to the next call and start executing instructions that same as usual?

Comment: dyp - alright, I'll add the full code underneath

Comment: Full code added. Looks like this might not have the simple solution I was expecting.

Comment: So what is `key_not_found_exception` and what do you think it might be used for? I don't see a problem here really.

Comment: What is this Pokémon exception handler doing in your `find` function? `catch(...){}` As far as I can see, you can resolve the entire problem by removing the try-catch at that point. Of course the rest of your function is executed if you catch and ignore the exception. Let the exception propagate to the caller.

Comment: It's just class key_not_found_exception {}; It doesn't really do anything other than get caught.

Comment: Your caller is expecting either a valid reference (as a function return "value") or an exception. But you catch the exception and ignore it within `find`, so it will not reach the caller of `find`.

Comment: dyp-well damn, I think that might have just done it. I'm confused, though, what is the issue here? Removing the try catch as you suggested seems to have cleared it up, but I'm not really sure why...

Comment: Ah, you added more. Well, that seems to have done the job, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, to return "failure" from a find-type function, one has two primary choices:

1. Return the element (or reference) that is found, otherwise throw an exception.
2. Return a *pointer* to the element, if it is found, or `nullptr` if not.

There are also other ways, such as returning a `bool` indicating success and returning the element found in an additional reference or pointer parameter.

In your case, returning `V &` reference, your only reasonable option to end the function without returning a value is to `throw` an exception.

Comment: A third, very important alternative is how the C++ Standard Library deals with the issue: `map::operator[]` creates a new entry in the map if the key could not be found, and returns a reference to either the existing or this new element.